# sql query to count number of -1's and 1's present in a column

Tags: sql, database

In a table named "table1" contains only 1 column named "column1" contains only -1 and 1.
how to write a query to get count of -1 and 1 in the column1 by giving the alias names using single query.

```
I should print like,

    positive 10
    negative 5
```

I am just able to print the count of number by writing the query like

```
select count(*) from table1 group by column1;
```

but how to give the alias name  to both numbers as positive and negative.

Comment: What do you mean by "alias name"?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `GROUP BY column1` and use a `CASE` expression that returns 'positive' or 'negative':

```
SELECT CASE column1 
         WHEN 1 THEN 'positive'
         WHEN -1 THEN 'negative' 
       END sign, 
       COUNT(*) counter
FROM table1
GROUP BY column1
```

But if there is a case that there are no positives or no negatives it is better to use conditional aggregation with `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT 'positive' sign, COUNT(CASE WHEN column1 = 1 THEN 1 END) counter FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'negative', COUNT(CASE WHEN column1 = -1 THEN 1 END) FROM table1
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=46ac7bda40f81c73105947635382dd91).

Answer (score 1):

you could use "sub-queries" like this:

```html
SELECT (select count(*) from table1 group by column1 having column1>0) POAITIVE,
(select count(*) from table1 group by column1 having column1<0) NEGATIVE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below Query and it should be work as you expected.

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN COLUMN1 = -1 THEN 'NEGATIVE'
    ELSE 'POSITIVE'
  END AS RESULT,
  COUNT(1) AS COUNT
FROM
  TABLE1
GROUP BY
  CASE
    WHEN COLUMN1 = -1 THEN 'NEGATIVE'
    ELSE 'POSITIVE'
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
'Positive' AS [Pos/Neg], 
SUM(CASE WHEN [column1] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Count] 
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT 
'Negative' AS [Pos/Neg], 
SUM(CASE WHEN [column1] = -1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Count]
FROM table1
```